# I want to add error message on top of the page after clicking submit button if the user leaves the input field empty in angular 6

Tags: angular-validation

There are multiple input fields. If the user fails to enter any of the input fields and click submit button (submit button will always be enabled). An error message should come on top of the page indicating i.e "first name is required". I need this in angular 6.
 we do have lots of good validation features in angular but i cant use that. The above is the exact requirement i need to come up with angular

Comment: Can you provide some source code, please?

Answer (score 0):

So, 
You can create a service like AlertMessageService injected in your angular component.
Secondly, you will have an AlertMessageComponent having a static method to show error.

From your service you will be calling the static method of your component to show the message.
Alert component will be having its selector which you can add on the first line of main component of your html

On clicking of your submit button you will use that service
like suppose your service is having Alert method which is internally calling the static method of Alert component

Comment: Thank you so much vishal. it would be really nice if you provide me the sample code of this thing

Comment: AlertMessageService an angular service with @Injectable decorator, it has a method suppose called Alert

Alert(message: string,errorType: string)
{
 
AlertComponent.show(message,errorType);

} 

AlertComponent have a show method with AletComponent.html
show(message,errorType) 
{
   this.message = message;
  
  //According to the type of error you can apply the class if you want to
}


AlertComponent.html
<div [ngClass] = "">
{{message}}
</div>